# Read and store the values from Excel rows to variables/arrays using VBscripting in UFT

Tags: excel, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Through UFT I am trying to read rows from an Excel sheet (can be any number of rows based on the user input). I want to pass these values (are string values) to another function.

The below code which gives subscript out of range error at line 'fieldvalueChar(j-1) = ws.cells(j,1)'

```
Dim value 
Dim lRow
Dim fieldvalue
Dim fieldvalueChar()
'Open the spreadsheet document for read-only access.
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("Path\Input.xlsx")

Set ws = objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
rowcount = ws.usedrange.rows.count

for j = 1 to rowcount
    fieldvalueChar(j-1) = ws.cells(j,1)

next

MsgBox(fieldvalueChar(0))
MsgBox(fieldvalueChar(1))
```

The Excel sheet will always have one column and dynamically changing number of rows based on the user input. I saw some VBA codes online but no VBS.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try, UFT's Data table functionality

Comment: Have not tried that yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you did not initialize the array. You can try something like this

```
Dim value 
Dim lRow
Dim fieldvalue
ReDim fieldvalueChar(1) ' Just Declare an array of 1, Since array size has to be constant when declaring 

'Open the spreadsheet document for read-only access.
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\saravananp\Desktop\Items.xls")

Set ws = objWorkbook.Sheets("Items")
rowcount = ws.usedrange.rows.count

' Redefine array size dynamically based on number of Rows 
ReDim fieldvalueChar(rowcount)

for j = 1 to rowcount
    fieldvalueChar(j-1) = ws.cells(j,1) 
next


MsgBox(fieldvalueChar(0))
MsgBox(fieldvalueChar(1))
```

In the other hand you could try datatables as well.

Comment: My Pleasure. Additionally subscript out of range is thrown when a Non-Existing array element is accessed. Ex: If an array is of Size 5, if you access 6 you will get that error. In your case your size is 0 so u'd get that error if u try to access any index. Check thisif you'd like more detail: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519(v=vs.60).aspx